# onScopeDispose vs scope.cleanups

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I was checking out some source code to make sure my event bus was properly cleaned up when components were destroyed and ran in to `scope.cleanups` (from https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/core/useEventBus/index.ts):

```js
const scope = getCurrentScope()
scope?.cleanups?.push(/* handler */)
```

Is this an undocumented alternative to `onScopeDispose` (https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#onscopedispose)? I can't seem to find any info about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scope?.cleanups?.push()` is almost the [same implementation in `onScopeDispose()`](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/8a123ac34fd30fc36ac9e0c252dd345d6d7c7f50/packages/reactivity/src/effectScope.ts#L124):

```js
export function getCurrentScope() {
  return activeEffectScope
}

export function onScopeDispose(fn: () => void) {
  if (activeEffectScope) {
    activeEffectScope.cleanups.push(fn) 
  }
  ⋮
}
```

One significant difference is the optional chaining on `cleanups` is absent from `onScopeDispose()`. The [git blame on that line in `useEventBus()`](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/commit/30f21fac82dec852bcd8ee0d1c42b7e9bd500285#diff-9c04e8febb00466ddfeee0848484e45463a27732be568e67c5dfd0e248911e39R53) indicates the optional chaining was added because `cleanups` is possibly undefined/null in Vue 2.

It seems using the official API (`onScopeDispose()`) is the better option, as `cleanups` is essentially a private implementation detail that users should not be aware of.